# Thymeleaf: From controller to html

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a table of values with an href.

```
<tr th:each="note : ${test}">
    <td th:text="${note.name}"><a href="@{/}"></a>></td>
    <td th:text="${note.lastName}"></td>
    <td th:text="${note.studentId}"></td>
    <td>
        <a th:href="@{'/seeStudent/' + ${note.studentId}}">Ver</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/seeStudent/{id}")
public String getStudentById(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("student", repo.findById(id));
    return "seeStudent";
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>Student information</h1>
    <ul>
        <div th:object="${student}">
            <li>
                <h4>
                    <span th:text="${name}"></span>
                </h4>
                <h4>
                    <span th:text="${lastName}"></span>
                </h4>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason the display is comming up blank, it is as if it wasn't finding the student by Id. When I debug it does locate the student and return it. I believe I may be doing something wrong when trying to pull the object data and display it in my html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `th:object`, your expression should be (with an asterisk) `*{name}` and `*{lastName}`.  If you want to use the equivalent (dollar sign) `${...}` expression, it would be `${student.name}` and `${student.lastName}`.